# Rails3 nested routes with default base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-routes, friendly-id

From the example in rails guides, routes like:

```
resources :publishers do
  resources :magazines do
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

Will lead to, URLs like:

```
/publishers/1/magazines/2/photos/3
```

I want to have slugs for publishers for example - Oxford
And avoid the first "/publishers" part
Making the URLs to something like:

```
/oxford/1/magazines/2/photos/3
```

What is the cleanest and best way to achieve this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :path => ":publisher_slug", :as => "publisher" do
  resources :magazines do
    resources :photos
  end
end

publisher_magazine_photo_path("oxford",2,3)
```